# FastCGI and Apache and C++

Tags: c++, apache, ubuntu, fastcgi

I comliled C++ project for FastCGI, copy executable file into www directory, open via browser - and got 500 error (timeout exeption). What do i wrong?

OS Ubuntu 10.05, server: Apache

source C++ code:

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h> /* fcgi library; put it first*/
#include <fcgiapp.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int count;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    /* Response loop. */
      while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)   {
        cout<<"Content-type: text/html\r\n"
               "\r\n"
               "<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>"
               "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>"
               "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n";
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're in the FCGI_Accept() loop you should be reading data, not writing it.

Check out http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/apaman.htm